# Emulator sony xperia S and samsung galaxy s3 (android)

Tags: android, emulation, skins

I developed an application in android, I need to test the application on samsung galaxy S3, xperia S,
how can I download the emulators.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create emulator images yourself.  The images are called Android Virtual Devices (AVDs).

There are lots of tutorials, but basically, you will need to create emulator images (AVDs) with the particular requirements of the devices you wish to emulate (for the most part, screen size will be the most important thing you will want to test).

Here is a link to the official docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html